# Find First Set instruction (ffs) for boost multiprecision uint512_t

Tags: c++, boost, bit-manipulation, avx512, boost-multiprecision

I'm developing an algorithm that uses `__builtin_ffsll()` with `uint64_t` type.

I want to switch to 512-bit field using boost multiprecision library (I'm running on a machine with avx512 support).

Is there a similar function as the mentioned builtin? Alternatively, how can I efficiently implement such functionality for 512-bit integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html#boost_multiprecision.ref.number.integer_functions):

> `unsigned lsb(const number-or-expression-template-type& x);`
>
> Returns the (zero-based) index of the least significant bit that is set to 1.
>
> Throws a `std::range_error` if the argument is `<= 0`.

`ffs()` is one-based, so adding 1 to `lsb()`'s return value will make it equivalent. Edit: And as pointed out, taking the case of being passed 0 into account.

Maybe something like

```
unsigned ffs512(const boost::multiprecision::uint512_t &n) {
  if (n.is_zero()) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return boost::multiprecision::lsb(n) + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note the different behaviour for input == 0.  It appears `lsb` is designed to wrap things like x86's `bsf` instruction which only sets a flag when the input is zero; it doesn't write a useful value to the output register.  But `ffs` does handle the input==0 case, returning `0`.

Comment: Does `lsb` on a 512-bit integer actually compile to an AVX512 sequence that uses `vptestmd` / `vpcompressd` or similar to find the first non-zero dword, then `vmovd` to extract it to an integer register for `tzcnt`?  (Or using 2x 256-bit vectors to avoid putting the CPU into 512-bit SIMD mode.)  The OP wants this to be efficient on x86, presumably with gcc and/or clang with `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512`

Comment: @PeterCordes I imagine the GMP backend calls `mpz_scan1()`. No clue about the others.

Comment: Godbolt doesn't have the GMP back-end installed :/  With the portable CPP back-end, gcc and clang use qword loops to check for a non-zero chunk, then `tzcnt` it.  https://godbolt.org/z/qEq_QE.  GCC still emits exception-creating functions but `ffs512` does optimize away any potential call to them.  AVX2 to just find the right dword or qword index for a scalar load would also have been good, vs. the AVX512 idea I suggested earlier.  `mpz_scan1()` is just written in C (https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpz/scan1.c), which uses the same limb search (at `short_cut:`) then trailing-zero bitscan.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think GMP only has the generic version of mp[nz]_scan1 because it was never the limiting factor, compared to multiplications or worse divisions and gcd. If you think it is useful and you can provide a faster version for large scans that does not significantly slow down the common case where the scan finds a 1 bit almost immediately, you could try contributing it to GMP. But indeed the OP has a simpler case to handle, always scanning from the beginning. And the current `lsb` is likely fast enough for them.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: yeah, the GMP version has to be much more flexible, with the size not being a compile-time constant.  I think we could detect large limb-count with a single extra check that might be negligible for small numbers.  But if the first `1` is in the first limb, then yes pure scalar is still much better (also avoids any risk of a store-forwarding stall from a wide load).  So maybe you'd want to start with that and only look at the size for maybe doing a SIMD search if not found in the first limb.  If not found in the first 64 bits, it's probably not in the next 64 either for large n.

Comment: Looks like this `uint512_t` is only typedefed for the `cpp_int` backend so it doesn't really matter for this question how the gmp backend implements it.